# Compare two times

Tags: sql, time, comparison

i want to compare between two times the first one is getting by the `resultset` of an sql query like the following:

```
res = req.executeQuery("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timespent))) FROM dailytimesheet where trackingdate=CURRENT_DATE and matricule=36;");
res.first();     
{
    retour.append("<td><label  style=\"background-color:#09F\" style=\"font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif\"  style=\"font-size:16px\"> Total Hours</label><td>"+res.getString(1)+ "</td>");
```

and the second time is: 07:30:00

so i want to display a message if the time containing in the `res.getString(1)` is bellow the time `07:30:00`.
i dont know how to achieve the comparison.

Comment: A little off topic. mixing style, markup, query into one single function? dude, you're doing it so wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have to create a Date/Time from the string and then diff it with a Date/Time of 07:30:00

in java: [date.compareTo(otherdate)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29) will return -1 if smaller, 0 if equal, +1 if higher

Comment: another option is to split the string on hours, minutes, seconds and calculate it yourself

Comment: third option is to do it in SQL, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html